# is spring.net being actively maintained/developed/documented?

Tags: spring.net

In the course of evaluating .net IoC frameworks, I gave spring.net a try first, seeing as how much I liked spring in java.  However, I'm rapidly getting the feeling that it is a stale/stalled/dead project.  The forums have almost no activity; the documentation, though verbose, is infuriating with its self-referencing, poor examples, and incomplete sections; spring.net questions don't seem to get much traction on stackoverflow; and googling for spring.net issues usually leads to pages documenting somewhat obscure scenarios.  I'm close to making the jump to Ninja or Castle, but I can see that their documentation doesn't exactly sparkle either.  Still, if everyone has poor documentation, I'd rather pick an active project.  What are your suggestions?

Comment: IMHO the documentation actually is OK; although I've also encountered minor errors in the example code in the documentation.

Comment: This is time-sensitive question. As of 21.03.2014 I see relatively low activity on their web site. But JIRA says that they planning to release 2.0 GA on 31.03.2014 - https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPRNET/fixforversion/12344/?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin:version-summary-panel

Comment: @Tornn they definitely missed the due date :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring.NET is pretty active.
Take a look to their bug tracking system :
https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPRNET

They have 2 full-time committers working on it.

Answer (score 0):

Spring is pretty active, as pointed out by Paul. Their IoC container is excellent, in my opinion. As I write this, they're actively working on a [code-config project at github](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-net-codeconfig/commits/master) .