# Spring.Net Framework sunset?

Tags: .net, spring, spring.net

I've been considering going back to the springframework for .net DI, but I just noticed that there hasn't been any recent development or announcements on [their site](http://www.springframework.net/index.html).  Can anyone confirm that they are still actively developing the .net version of the spring framework, or is the project dead?

I know this has been asked before ([is spring.net being actively maintained/developed/documented?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881818/is-spring-net-being-actively-maintained-developed-documented?rq=1)), but that was over 2 years ago.  The last announcement on the site's homepage is from December 2012.

---

Some more evidence of it being dead:

1. The [forums](http://forum.springframework.net/) site is down, for how long I don't know
2. There is no spring.net project on the [download page](http://spring.io/projects?project=Spring.NET)
3. The build has been failing on the [jira site](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/#selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.ext.bamboo:bamboo-project-tabpanel) since May 2013

Comment: fwiw former spring.net dev lead [Steve Bohlen](http://stackoverflow.com/users/23208/sbohlen) has left Springsource [for Microsoft January 2013](http://www.linkedin.com/in/sbohlen).

Comment: try tweeting/sharing this question to [@springfornet](https://twitter.com/SpringForNet)

Comment: That sounds familiar ...

Comment: related: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-net/issues/53

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have a look at the GitHub repo

there was a recent check-in (a few hours ago of this comment being posted)
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-net/commits/master

also gives you an idea to who is developing the library.

forum looks to be up and running.

however that said, the same question is being asked on the forum 
http://forum.springframework.net/showthread.php?10866-Current-state-of-the-Spring-NET-project

Comment: I'm calling it dead, no response to the initial question in over 2 months, and one lone commit.

Comment: Looks like someone is trying to bring it back on github, going to mark this as answer since it pointed me to the github repo for it.

Answer (score 5):

I can refer only to this part "I've been considering going back to the springframework for .net DI" . Definitely it is not worth to do that. There is a wide range of good DI frameworks in .NET. In comparison with them Spring.NET is outdated. Mainly because of XML based configuration. There is a subproject to provide XML-less configuration but it is not finished. It can't be compared even with Java's original Spring configuration.

That said I'm going to use Spring.Net even if it is abandoned project. This is because it has other goodies too:

- AOP integrated with DI;
- libraries to use DI easily, for example when using WCF or ASP.MVC;
- ADO.NET transactions handling; this allows us to write components which later can be configured to work within different transaction contexts even with drivers not supporting TransactionScope.

Comment: I think you get all those things with the http://castleproject.org as well, and it is still being developed

Comment: I think castle had project for transaction management, but it looks like also abandoned - more that a year no commit, link from main castle project does not work.

Answer (score 3):

2.0 is GA finally. so it is still active.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-net/releases/tag/spring-net-2.0.0-GA